# Get Credit card number after payment Done

Tags: react-native, applepay

I am using `react-native-payment` package for doing payment with apple pay.

After payment done I need credit card number which is used for payment.

I am using `payment.show()`function for doing payment. Once payment done I am getting response with payment data.

So any one please help me how can I get credit card number from it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apple and Google Pay don’t provide the merchant with any card details, only a Payment Token so it’s not possible to do this. You supply the token to a payment provider (eg Stripe, Worldpay) and they use it to process the actual payment.